# Publish ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

After I finished an MVC4 Project i want to publish it on a local IIS Server.
Now I don't know how i have to publish my project and I also don't know how to use the IIS Server!

Can anyone explain this to me in simple words( Beginner!)

Comment: Have you searched the web for the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice tutorial for a beginner.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-deploying-to-iis-as-a-test-environment-5-of-12